# Why do the rows of Table1 on post back become null?

Tags: c#

**The problem is:** *On postback, the table does not have the rows that were dynamically created, the rowcount is 0.*

- Click on the button, it should detect the checked checkboxes within the table dynamically generated.
- The table is made by code when the "day" is selected using the drop down list and "the starting date" is selected using the calender.

I know there's a lot of code, but it's the least I thought I had to post, so answerers can debug. Please note I have tried hard but cannot get the solution to this.

Here’s the code:

```
public partial class DaySelection : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Table table1 = new Table();
    Button button1 = new Button();
    string the_id_checkbox;
    string the_id_label;
    //The need of the table ENDS
    DropDownList selectdays = new DropDownList();
    Label theselecteddate = new Label();
    Button extract_the_selected = new Button();
    Literal selected_values=new Literal();
    int number_of_row = -1;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox check_or_not = new CheckBox();
        try
        {
            selected_values.Text = "";
            form1.Controls.Remove(selected_values);
            form1.Page.Response.Write("inside try");
            for (int i = 0; i < table1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Response.Write("inside for");
                the_id_checkbox = "checkmate" + i;
                the_id_label = "The_text" + i;
                check_or_not = (CheckBox)table1.Rows[i].FindControl(the_id_checkbox);
                if (check_or_not.Checked == true)
                {
                    form1.Page.Response.Write("inside if");
                    selected_values.Text = selected_values.Text + "<br /> " + check_or_not.Checked.ToString();
                    selected_values.Text = selected_values.Text + "  and the day is:  " + ((Label)table1.Rows[i].FindControl(the_id_label)).Text;
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write(" selection no detect");
                }
            }
            form1.Controls.AddAt(1, selected_values);
            Response.Write(selected_values.Text);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException nn)
        {
            form1.Page.Response.Write("inside catch" + nn.Message.ToString() + nn.StackTrace);
        }
        extract_the_selected.Text = "Extract it";
        form1.Controls.AddAt(2,extract_the_selected);
        selectdays.AutoPostBack = true;
        ArrayList thedays = new ArrayList();
        thedays.Add("Monday" + DateTime.Now);
        thedays.Add("Tuesday");
        thedays.Add("Wednesday");
        thedays.Add("Thursday");
        thedays.Add("Friday");
        thedays.Add("Saturday");
        thedays.Add("Sunday");
        selectdays.DataSource = thedays;
        selectdays.DataBind();
        form1.Controls.AddAt(3,selectdays);
        Calendar1.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(Calendar1_SelectionChanged);
    }

    void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime startdate;
        string month;
        month = Calendar1.SelectMonthText;
        startdate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
        days_date(startdate);
    }

    void selectdays_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        display_dates_of_day(DateTime.Parse("9-1-2010"), DateTime.Parse("9-30-2010"), selectdays.SelectedItem.Text);
    }

    public void days_date(DateTime startdate)
    {
        int noofdays;
        DateTime enddate = new DateTime();
        noofdays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(startdate.Year, startdate.Month) - 1;
        enddate = startdate.AddDays(noofdays);
        Response.Write("<br /> end date is  " + enddate);
        Response.Write("<br /> start date is " + startdate);
        display_dates_of_day( startdate, enddate, selectdays.SelectedItem.Text);
    }

    void display_dates_of_day(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string selectedday)
    {
        int Count = 0;
        for (DateTime dt = startDate; dt <= endDate; dt = dt.AddDays(1.0))
        {
            if (dt.DayOfWeek.ToString() == selectedday)
            {
                table1.ID = "table1";
                number_of_row = number_of_row + 1;
                string date = dt.Date.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
                for (int adding_rows = 0; adding_rows < 1; adding_rows++)
                {
                    TableRow table_row1 = new TableRow();
                    TableCell table_cell1 = new TableCell();
                    TableCell table_cell2 = new TableCell();
                    Label The_label = new Label();
                    CheckBox checkmate = new CheckBox();
                    The_label.Text = date + " (<---date)" + number_of_row;
                    the_id_checkbox = "checkmate" + number_of_row;
                    checkmate.ID = the_id_checkbox;
                    the_id_label = "The_text" + number_of_row;
                    The_label.ID = the_id_label;
                    table_cell2.Controls.Add(checkmate);
                    table_cell1.Controls.Add(The_label);
                    table_row1.Controls.AddAt(0, table_cell1);
                    table_row1.Controls.AddAt(1, table_cell2);
                    table1.Rows.Add(table_row1);
                }
                button1.Text = "click me to export the value";
                form1.Controls.Add(table1);
                form1.Controls.AddAt(1, selected_values);
                Count++;
            }
        }
        Response.Write("<br /> The count of days by traversing:  " + Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 to question for the comment

Comment: Try setting break points and follow the code

Comment: i gave twenty minutes in trying to format this thing, how did u do it so fast? adding space to each line is a headache for it to be registered as code by the edittor

Comment: @user try using the '>' symbol

Comment: @Timwi, whilst I agree with *some* of the sentiment, there's criticism and there's constructive criticism, your comment is edging towards the former rather than the latter.

Comment: @user287745 - there's a button at the top of the question box that's two rows of 1's and 0's. If you highlight the block of text that you want to make into a code snippet and click that button, it'll indent every line by 4 spaces for you. No adding spaces to every line by hand =)

Comment: o okay @ yes i kept break point, theres nothing wrong.. on wrking

Comment: @Rob: I’m sorry you feel that way. The criticism was certainly intended to be constructive. It was my hope that the user would be more willing to put effort into formatting their future questions before expecting other users to put effort into their answers.

Comment: @user287745: How did I do it so fast? I pasted it into my editor, removed all the commented-out code, search-and-replaced `\n\n` with `\n` to remove all the blank lines, pressed Ctrl+A followed by Tab to indent everything, and then pasted it back.

Comment: @Timwi, +1 for the "How I did it" comment, that's what I mean by constructive! Your first comment comes across as a bit abrasive and harsh, hence my comment. =)

Comment: @user287745, I've tried to tidy up the wording of the title and non-code part of your question to make it more palatable to people reviewing it - please undo any changes that you feel are detrimental to your question =)

Comment: Since you claim you actually tried to format the code, I'm moving my vote to a +1 ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this seemingly "strange" behaviour is that you're dynamically constructing the contents of `Table1` and adding it to the pages `.Controls` collection only in the `display_dates_of_day` method, which is called by:

- `selectdays_SelectedIndexChanged`
- `Calendar1_SelectionChanged` (indirectly)

This means that when your page is re-contructed on post-back, the controls don't exist. If you "View Source" in your browser, you'll find that after clicking the button to trigger a post-back you can't find the string "Table1" in the markup, but if you do it after clicking on a date in the calendar, you can. That's because in the "clicking the button" scenario, *the control is never populated and added to the page*

I'd make a few suggestions to get your head round this and solve the problem:

1. Start with a much simplified version of this to help you understand the [asp.net page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) and how it impacts on what you're doing.
2. Try to ensure your code adds as **few controls as possible** to the page dynamically as this makes things a lot simpler. i.e. Make `Table1` a control that's declared in the `.aspx` page.

Comment: point 2, if i drag the table control onto page on design time, will it solve the problem? (i will still be adding rows by code)

Comment: @user287745, try it and see =) (That said, it'll not solve the problem because `table1` will be on the page, but won't contain any rows. You need to ensure that the relevant rows are added irrespective of whether the page is called via a button click postback, or one from clicking on a date in the calendar)

Comment: please check this link, have added a proper question help there if can thanks   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646356/dynamic-creation-adding-row-and-cols-in-table-works-but-on-button-click-things